# Singleton over collections of objects in Java and garbage collector

Tags: java

I'm using a singleton for granting a unique copy of each object in runtime:

```
Car object1= CarFactory.createCar(id);
```

where the createCar method is:

```
private static ArrayList<Car> cars= new ArrayList<Car>();

public static synchronized Car createCar(int id){
   Car result= new Car(id);
   int index= cars.indexOf(result);
   if (index==-1){
      cars.add(result);
      return result;
   } else {
      return cars.get(index);
   }
}
```

The problem is that with this method each Car have always an reference due to the "cars" collection and the object's memory is never released. How can I improve it?

Comment: Shouldn't `cars` be `static`?

Comment: Yes it was an transcript error

Comment: The first thing I'd do is remove the mutable statics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to wrap the objects before putting them in the list. Example:

```
private static List<WeakReference<Car>> cars = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Car>>();

public static synchronized Car createCar(int id) {
   WeakReference<Car> result= new WeakReference<Car>(new Car(id));
   int index= cars.indexOf(result);
   if (index==-1){
      cars.add(result);
      return result.get();
   } else {
      return cars.get(index).get();
   }
}
```

Note: This is not production code. You will have to build some more safeguards before using it.

Comment: issue: WeakReference.equals doesn't check what it references so index will always be -1, use a iterator loop instead (and remove the weakrefs that have already been collected)

Comment: @ratchetfreak As I said: Definitely not production code.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I *suppose* you could keep a list of [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s. A weak reference is not strong enough to keep an object from being garbage collected.

Ex:

```
    List<WeakReference<Point>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Point p = new Point();
    list.add(new WeakReference<>(p));
    System.out.println(p);
    System.out.println(list.get(0).get());

    p = null;

    System.gc();
    System.gc();
    System.gc();
    System.gc(); // hopefully the GC collects p by now

    System.out.println(list.get(0).get()); // null!
```

However, unless you're creating a large number of `Car`s and memory is *actually* an issue, it is probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit of a hack but you can use

```
WeakHashMap<Car,WeakReference<Car>> cars=new WeakHashMap<Car,WeakReference<Car>>();

public static synchronized Car createCar(int id){
   Car result= new Car(id);
   WeakReference<Car> weakCar=cars.get(result);
   if(weakCar==null){
       cars.put(new WeakReference(result));
       return result;
   }
   Car val= weakCar.get();
   if (val==null){//it may have been collected between cars.get() and weakCar.get()
      cars.put(new WeakReference(result));
      return result;
   } else {
      return val;
   }
}
```

note that you need the weakref as value because the value is considered a strong ref

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work because cars.get(result) returns always run (even overriding equals method at Car)

Comment: @Addev did you also override Car's `hashcode()` (just return id)